# PETSc: OMP+MKL in MatShell

Tags: openmp, intel-mkl, petsc

I am trying to use a custom matvec operator with PETSc MatShell in Fortran and inside of it, I want to use a mix of OpenMP and MKL multithreading (blas).

The OpenMP and MKL threads are indeed launched, but htop shows that only the OpenMP threads occupy 200% of the CPU (2 threads at 100%) when there are 48 cores available.

I can indeed see the rest of the threads (MKL) on htop but they use 0% of CPU.

How can I achieve this?

Edit: I'm glad to post more details. I'm shooting for a short message first in case someone has run into the same issue.

Comment: PETSc is based on MPI parallelism. Are you running just one petsc process?

Comment: I am using MPI. OpenMP and MKL are not being used by PETSc regardless of the amount of MPI processes.

Comment: If you're using MPI, say 12 processes on your 48 cores, then each process can only have 4 threads. At least, most job starters will set it up that way.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout Problem is, with 1 MPI process, two OpenMP threads are launched, and MKL is working single-core. There is some interaction between PETSc and the rest of the software making MKL not using multithreading.

Comment: MKL has different libraries for sequential/multi-threaded. You need to link the right one.

Comment: Thanks @VictorEijkhout It is indeed linking to the parallel ones: "-lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_core -lmkl_intel_thread -lmkl_blacs_openmpi_lp64" It is just not working inside the matvec operator of a MatShell

Comment: Could you let us know the OS details, hardware, and complete steps you have followed with the sample reproducer code to investigate your issue more?

Comment: Thank you @Varsha-Intel, the problem seems to be related to MKL only, could you please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76001117/mkl-blas-not-multithreading-zgemv ?